# Geometry, finding the possible values of 'a'

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

$P (a,4)$, $Q (2,3)$, $R (3,-1)$ and $S (-2,4)$ are four points.
If $|PQ| = |RS|$, find the possible values of a

I know this is a pretty basic problem but I'm having a lot of trouble with it, here is my answer:

I found $|RS|$ to be $\sqrt{50}$  so |PQ| = sqrt-2a^2 + 1 = sqrt50
and from there I got $\sqrt{8}$ which is incorrect because that is only one value.

The true answer should be; $-5$ or $9$ (according to textbook)

What is the proper method that I should use to come to the correct solution?

Comment: Please consider learning [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your mathematics. A helpful user edited most of your formulas, but neither he or I was able to understand "sqrt-2a^2+1"; something seems to be missing.

Comment: This bit here:  |PQ| = sqrt-2a^2 + 1 = sqrt50  I'm not sure what you're trying to say here;  this is likely where you've gone wrong, and unfortunately it's kind of a symbol salad as is.  If you want to put a bunch of stuff underneath a square root symbol, do like this: `$\sqrt{d^2+(4-3)^2}$`.  The $ symbols tell the program to think about what's between them as math, and display it accordingly.

Comment: Oh, so sorry about that, I'm new here, I'll definitely take a look into MathJax but what i meant was  -2a to the power of 2 + 1 all under a square root. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There's two things that have gone wrong here.

The first is that you have incorrectly calculated the horizontal distance (I'll call it $d$) between P and Q.  It should be

$$\sqrt{50} = \sqrt{d^2+(4-3)^2}$$
$$50 = d^2+1^2$$
$$d^2=49$$
$$d=7$$
The second is, once you've gotten a distance value, you can then use it to find the possible values of $a$: it could be $2 + 7 = 9$ or $2 - 7 = -5$, as both are 7 units away from Q horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You know that
$$ \sqrt{50}= \lvert RS \rvert = \lvert PQ\rvert = \sqrt{(a-2)^2+(4-3)^2} = \sqrt{a^2-4a+4+1} = \sqrt{a^2-4a+5},$$
so a good starting point would be to find the $a$ so that $50 = a^2-4a+5$.

Comment: Hey sorry, to only get back to you on this but why isn't it 2-a but rather a-2. Isn't the formula for d=/sqrt. (x2 - x1)^2  etc. ?

Comment: @PositiveAlf: The result is the same, $(-x)^2 = x^2$ for all numbers $x$. Think of it this way: the distance from $P$ to $Q$ is exactly the same as the distance from $Q$ to $P$.